# Angular: How to capture checkbox change event and update content in a non-parent component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a component which has a checkbox. `<mat-checkbox class="mr-5"></mat-checkbox>` I need to capture when it is checked, and then display text in another component based on the checkbox tick/selection. The second component is not the parent of the component which has the check box.

How can I capture the checkbox value change, from the non-parent component? I am new to Angular. Really appreciate if I could get an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exists different ways for implement transfer events between components. I think that better create service:

```
//SERVICE
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ 
  providedIn: 'root' 
})
export class ChangeService {
    private checkEvent = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    check = this.checkEvent.asObservable();

    constructor() {
    }

    onChangeCheck(data: boolean) {
        this.checkEvent.next(data);
    }
}

//COMPONENT WITH CHECKBOX
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private service: ChangeService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onChange(event) {
    this.service.onChangeCheck(event.checked);
  }

}

//COMPONENT WITH TEXT
export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {

  isVisibleText = false;

  constructor(
    private service: ChangeService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.check
      .subscribe(checked => {
          this.isVisibleText = checked;
      });    
  }

}
```

Comment: Spot on ! This worked ! BehaviourSubject and Observer did the trick. Thank you @V.Tur

Answer (score 1):

try this one,

in HTML

```
<mat-checkbox class="mr-5" (click)="onChecked($event)"></mat-checkbox>
```

in TS

```
onChecked(e){

  if(e.target.checked){
   //  check box Checked
  }else{
   //  check box unChecked
  }

}
```