# Rxjs: Behavior Subject emits value without calling next()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm creating a multi select filter with RxJs, and using an angular service to communicate values between components.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
export class SomeService{

    private readonly defaulFilterSelect: SomeSelect[] = 
    [
      {
          id: 1,
          label: 'label 1',
          options: [
              { id: 2, isChecked: false},
              { id: 3, isChecked: false}
          ]
      },
      {
          id: 7,
          label: 'Label 2',
          type: { name: 'checkbox' },
          options: [
              { id: 4, isChecked: false},
              { id: 5, isChecked: false}
          ]
      }
    ]

    private filterSelectDataSource = new BehaviorSubject<SomeSelect[]>(this.defaulFilterSelect);

    filterSelectData$ = this.filterSelectDataSource.asObservable();

    public get getFilterSelectData(){
      return this.filterSelectDataSource.value;
    }
}
```

The thing is, when a user does some work in the application, the property `isChecked` of the `SomeSelect` class can turn true, and later the user has the possibility to return to the initial state where all the properties named "isChecked" were `false`.
So I thought well if I need my observable to return to the initial state why not just  `next()` my default initial value `defaulFilterSelect`

```
    uncheckAllOptions(){
      this.filterSelectDataSource.next(this.defaulFilterSelect); //here
  }
```

For some reason this is not working as I would expect, and when I console log in on a subscribe I get the prior value of my observable.
Furthermore, if I modify the object `this.filterSelectDataSource.value`, without calling `next(obj)` the UI listens the changes and render the changes which is really confusing to me, as I expect that only calling `this.filterSelectDataSource.next(someNewObject);` would trigger changes in the UI that consume that observable.

Anyone can point me to the right direction here? thanks!

Comment: See please my answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64149570/angular-how-to-capture-checkbox-change-event-and-update-content-in-a-non-parent/64149907#64149907. You shouldn't modify your source without next().

Comment: 1) .getValue() (not .value) 2) only .next() 3) is your component code correct? change detection? subscription? etc.

Comment: thanks @an for your insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to deep clone `defaulFilterSelect` when you set it as your initial value on `filterSelectDataSource`, otherwise when you update it, you are updating the same *reference* of `defaulFilterSelect`.

How you deep clone is up to you, but I generally use Lodash [`cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep).

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that